# Как изменить значение внутри класса?

Tags: javascript

Внутри на html  страничке есть тег span с классом .test__1 (этот тег с этим классом встречается на этой страничке раз 5-6, как сделать так чтоб внутри этого тега я менял значение и оно менялось не у одного тега а у всех.

```
<span class="test__1">123</span>
<span class="test__1">124</span>
<span class="test__1">125</span>
```

Пробовал вот такой вариант - но он меняет значение только у одного тега - а нужно чтоб сразу менялось у всех.

```
const cl = document.querySelector('.test__1')
cl.textContent = 'Значение 1'
console.log(cl)
```

Спасибо за понимание.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо `querySelector` есть ещё и "querySelector**All**"

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test__1').forEach(el => {
    el.textContent = 'Значение 1'
});
```

```html
<span class="test__1">123</span>
<span class="test__1">124</span>
<span class="test__1">125</span>
```